# Understand proof of lemma about existence/uniqueness of group generated by a set

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

The definition of a subgroup generated by a set is given as:

> Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a subset of $G$. We define the *subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by $S$* to be a subgroup of $G$ satisfying a) $S \subseteq H$ and b) if $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $S \subseteq K$ then $H \subseteq K$.

---

The lemma is

> Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a subset of $G$. Then the group generated by $S$ exists and is unique.

I'm not understanding the purpose of the above lemma.

Certainly not *every* subset of a group $G$ will be able to generate a group? For example, any one-element subset of $G$ that does not contain the identity $e$ can't be a group.

But if I already must know before applying the lemma that $S$ generates a group, then why do I need to prove that the group generated by $S$ exists? (Because I already know it exists.)

Maybe I'm misundestanding the purpose of this lemma.

Comment: Definitions vary, so I have to ask how does the author define "group generated by $S$"?

Comment: I think you should review the definition of "group generated by $S$." You are correct that a singleton subset containing a non-identity element cannot be a group, but the "group generated by this singleton subset" is not the subset itself (it is necessarily larger).

Comment: Thanks for the hints, it makes sense to include the definition. I'm still not entirely sure hpw to bring the definition and the lemma together. Because by definition the group generated by $S$ as a subgroup. But then what's the lemma for?

Comment: Now that you have given the definition your book uses I think that you have an excuse for your confusion. The book ought in the definition to have said somethinh like "We say that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is generated by $S$ if (i) $S\subseteq H$ and (ii) for all subgroups $K$ of $G$ with $S\subseteq K$ we have $H\leqslant K$." So you then do need to prove: (a) such an $H$ exists (b) any two such are equal. The book ought not to have  said so soon "$H$ is the subgroup generated by $H$"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition says that the subgroup generated by the subset $S$ is a subgroup with certain properties. But just making that statement does not guarantee that such a subgroup exists.

So really before you make that definition you ought to prove that such a subgroup really does exist, and also that there is a unique subgroup that has those properties.

In other words, you should prove the lemma first i.e. prove that for any subset $S$ of the group there is unique subgroup that has the property described in the definition. Once you have proved the lemma you can make the definition.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, any subset *generates* a subgroup. Not every subset *is* a subgroup.

For example, consider group $\mathbb Z_4 = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Then subset $\{2\}$ generates subgroup $\{0, 2\}$.

The definition you cited can be reformulated to make meaning of lemma more clear: for $H$ - subgroup of $G$, we say that $H$ is generated by $S$, if [necessary properties hold]. The lemma now says that for any subset $S$ there is a subgroup $H$ s.t. $H$ is generated by $S$.

This $H$ is not necessary $S$ itself (and often is not), it can be some proper superset of $S$.

The lemma is non-trivial, because if we change definition of "subgroup generated by $S$", there not necessary is one. For example, if we define "subgroup $H$ is mihaild-generated by set $S$ if it is subgroup containing $S$ and having size at most $2|S|$", then there is no subgroup in $\mathbb Z_4$ that is mihaild-generated by set $\{1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just added the definition of the book for further context.

Comment: Maybe because my English isn't good enough but I'm not following the difference "Any subset generates a subgroup." vs.  "Not every subset is a subgroup.". Can you expand a bit on that?

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_6$, the subset $\{2\}$ is not a subgroup, but  it generates the subgroup $\{0,2,4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's useful to see another definition of the subgroup generated by a subset.

> **Definition:** Let $G$ be a group with $S \subseteq G$. Let
> $$
> \langle S \rangle = \bigcap_{S \subseteq H \leq G} H.
> $$
> Then $\langle S \rangle$ is called the **subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$.**

You should show that this definition and your definition are equivalent. First show that the arbitrary intersection of subgroups of $G$ is itself a subgroup of $G$.

With this definition, I think it's more clear why any subset of $G$ may generate a subgroup, because the construction is explicit, unlike in your definition. This definition also makes your lemma very clear; we can certainly always perform this construction, and it's straightforward to see $\langle S \rangle$ is unique.

---

Just my two cents, but this is the "more standard" definition, for a subgroup generated by a subset. If you do more algebra you'll see it over and over again so it's best to absorb it now. For example the *subring* or  generated by a subset are defined completely analogously, take intersections of all subrings of containing your subset. I also found it helped me get a feel for constructing "smallest" structures with particular properties, which you see in lots of different areas.

For example you encounter a completely analogous construction in analysis. Let $\Omega$ be a $\sigma$-algebra defined on a set $X$. Then if $R$ is an arbitrary collection of subsets of $X$, one can generate a unique, minimal sigma-algebra, $\sigma(R)$, generated by $R$ in the exact same way: Take the intersection of all sigma-algebras in $\Omega$ which contain $R$.